# Rotation of a profile using the "Curve to Mesh" node in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, transform-orientation, vector

So, I have a small hair simulation setup I imported from Houdini using an alembic *Mesh Sequence Cache* modifier. It is one curve object and all the points of these curves are slightly shifted:

[image: hair curves]

To give them a profile I tried using Geometry Nodes' *Curve to Mesh* node with a curve circle as a profile curve...

[image: hair profile and geo-nodes_01]

...but unfortunately I can't figure out how to orient this profile so every hair profile is rotated the same way:

[image: orientation profile]

As far as I know the *Set Curve Tilt* node only tilts every hair simultaniously, so maybe there is a way using the *Curve Tangent* node?

I also tried to make it work using the *Instance on Points* node, since it has a rotation input and there was an explanation on how to use the *Align Euler to vector* node, but then i'd have to use cyclinders with no caps as an instance and merge their points by distance. This seemed like a dirty workaround to me and I'd rather prefer to make it work using a curve profile.

I'm glad for any help! Thx in advance.
Cheers!

Comment: Rotate the Profile Curve. Clear Curve tilt (set to 0)

Comment: unfortunately rotating the profile curve will just rotate the hair as a whole but won't align the profile in one direction

Comment: So you don't want to rotate all curves in the same direction, you want to align them. *" so every hair profile is rotated the same way"* is misleading, you don't actually want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the *Curve Tilt* to $0$ will not help you, because when using `Curve to Mesh` the tangents of the curve ultimately decide the orientation of the mesh.

So in this case you would have to correct the tilt of the individual points.

A possible solution could look like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>

---

Or an even simpler solution might look like this:

[image]

Comment: oh wow ! ^^'  this is genius. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hmmm... What if you rotat each spline, so it's horizontal, and then set normal to z-up and rotate back?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Hm, that should also work (to be honest, I haven't tested it). However, there must then never be a vertical line.